# How to implement a textview that changes to match my image in a galleryview?

Tags: android

I have a galleryview with some pictures of my local swans, and I would like to have a textview that changes with the pictures.

My working code is below. At the moment I simply have a galleryview with an imageswitcher. 
From my googling I reckon I need to use an array adapter with text strings, but I haven't been able to find a way to make it work. As you can probably tell, I am very much in the early stages of learning Java!

Any help or advice pointing me in the correct direction would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity 
implements ViewFactory
{    
//---the images to display---
Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.swan1,
        R.drawable.swan2,
        R.drawable.swan3,
        R.drawable.swan4,
        R.drawable.swan5,
        R.drawable.swan6                  
};

private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;

@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displayview);

    imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher1);
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in));
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out));

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
            imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        }
    });  
}

 public View makeView() 
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new 
            ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    return imageView;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;

        //---setting the style---                
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();                                                    
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item--- 
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
        return imageView;
    }
   }    
    }
```

I have my strings in an array as follows:

arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array
    name="swan">
    <item>swan_1</item>
    <item>swan_2</item>
    <item>swan_3</item>
    <item>swan_4</item>
    <item>swan_5</item>
    <item>swan_6</item>
    <item>swan_7</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Following the information given to me by Hakan I know what I have to do; I just can't make it work. I have been trying extensively to make this work, but my java knowledge is still too bad. Any further help or would be very welcome indeed, this is causing me a major headache.

displayview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageSwitcher 
    android:id="@+id/switcher1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"                 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"      
    /> 
<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip" 
    /> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    />
</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom layout and use that for each item in the Gallery i.e. a layout which contains an ImageView and a TextView. It would be to good to use a FrameLayout. Android have given a great example and explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html). Once you get the layout, you would need to get the TextView object from this layout in your getView method and set the correct message.

To set the correct message I would have an ArrayList of Strings and then in getView I would simply retrieve the String at "position" in the ArrayList and set it to be the message of the TextView.

Comment: Heya Hakan, I am still stuck on this. Your answer has shown what I have to do, unfortunately I cannot work how to do it. My google fu has failed me. IF you or ayone else would be kind enough to help me I would be very grateful. Many thanks for taking the time to respond!